# Flexbox and Left Sidebar Overlay

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I get the left sidebar to overlay the content instead of pushing the content?  I want it overlay on mobile but push on web layout. Flexbox is a little new to me so not sure if I need a different layout to do this or if this is possible with flexbox? I'm guessing I need to remove the sidebar from the flexbox and use a fixed relative layout ??

I'm also using angular but I removed the angular code just for simplicity so don't mind the extra divs please.

```
<div class="wrapper">        
    <header class="header">
        header       
    </header> 

    <div class="main">            
        <div class="left-sidebar">
            left sidebar          
        </div>

        <div class="main-content-wrapper">    
             <div class="main-content">    
                <h3>Main </h3>     
             </div>     

             <footer class="footer">
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>              
             </footer> 
        </div>       
     </div>
</div>

body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header {
    min-height: 60px;   
    flex: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: silver;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;  

    .main {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;     


        .main-content-wrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex: 1;
            flex-direction: column;
            overflow: auto;


            .main-content {
                padding: 2rem;
                flex: 1;
                background-color: antiquewhite;
            }

            footer {
                background-color: silver;
                min-height: 300px;
                flex-shrink: 0;
            }
        }
    }

}

.left-sidebar {
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    flex: none;


    &.active {
        width: 250px;
    }

    .left-sidebar-content {
        padding: 1rem;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I actually made pretty much a new structure, although not that different to yours, (did remove some elements just to work with less code); I'm using flexbox to make the whole wrapper a flex container, as well as media queries to indicate when the sidebar should *push* the content to the side, and when to *overlap* the content along with an overlay.

```js
document.getElementById('toggleBtn').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('active');
  document.getElementById('overlay').classList.toggle('hidden');
}

document.getElementById('overlay').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('overlay').classList.toggle('hidden');
  document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 230px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -230px;
  /* top layer */
  z-index: 3
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

@media (max-width: 580px) {
  #sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    /* top layer */
    z-index: 3
  }
  .overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.425);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .overlay.hidden {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-sidebar" id="sidebar">
    left sidebar
  </div>

  <div class="main-content-wrapper">
    <div class="main-content">
      <h3>Main </h3>

      <button type="button" id="toggleBtn">Toggle</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay hidden" id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can you achieve that the sidebar act as overlay?

Comment: @nhaberl if you run this snippet on a smaller screen, you'll see the sidebar acts as an overlay, you can check the styles declared on the media-query on the snippet, that's what I use to change the behavior of the sidebar